# Where should I store a CSS file to be used across apps and libraries in my monorepo?

Tags: angular, nrwl

I created my own CSS framework/library (not sure of what to call it yet as its still growing) and I want to add it to my monorepo to use in all my apps.  Normally this would be the main `styles.css` file in my app but working with the monorepo structure there is no core `assets` folder or anything I can recognize as a good place to save it.  I'm also curious about how it would need to be imported into my apps, would it be as simple as importing it into the `styles.css` file in each app?  Or am I going to have to pass it into them as a module first?

Answer (score 0):

ok I just figured it out.

1. Create the css file at the top level of the monorepo.
2. Find the `styles` property of the project and add the new css file to the array with the default `styles.css` file.

From that point forwards you can use the styles in your app.